# Difference between Serverless Framework and CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework

I am new in Serverless Framework and CloudFormation my however i used serverless little bit for deploying Lambda function and somewhere i read that Serverless using CloudFormation inside so

My question is Can i do all things from Serverless Framework which is possible from CloudFormation.

Actually my Boss gave me task so create CloudFormation code to Build APIGateWay, code pipeline, code build, s3 and many other things from cloudFormation code so i am wonder is it possible to all things from serverless Framework itself?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Cloudformation is a service provided by AWS, while Serverless is a thirdparty product/solution that makes infrastructure-as-code (IaC) possible. There are others too for example, Terraform.

When deploying resources in AWS, Serverless almost always employs Cloudformation. The main differentiator being Serverless is more polished, has associated eco-system of tools to build, manage and monitor the infrastructure. Cloudformation does the deployment part, while Cloudwatch does the monitoring.

AWS SAM is another option, compared to writing vanilla Cloudformation code, which is more closer to Serverless, where a lot of boilerplate code is abstracted away, at the end, like Serverless, AWS SAM also builds Cloudformation stack.

Comment: first thanks for answer and i have few question 1 till now i understand i can do all things from serverless .yml code same which i can do from cloudformation .yml code right? 2 can i see what code generating in cloudformation when i use serverless so i can show boht .yml( serverless and cloudformation) to my boss 3

Comment: If you deploy serverless, it creates and deploys a Cloudformation stack. You can then go to Cloudformation service and see the deployed code there.